# What is the good design of database schema for a multiple-choice quiz engine?

Tags: database-design

I have a project to create  an asp.net mvc site to generate a quiz.
Here is the specification:

1. For each user visiting the site, she/he gets a quiz.
2. Each quiz contains some multiple-choice problems.
3. Each problem contains a question and 5 mutually-exclusive choices.

The simplest model I can think of is as follows:

```
    public class Problem
    {
        public int ProblemId { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
        public string C { get; set; }
        public string D { get; set; }
        public string E { get; set; }
    }
```

I am not sure it is good. 
Could you give me a suggestion for a better design?

Comment: "Stack Overflow"? the site has become sentient and is asking questions too?

Comment: I'm amazed that someone didn't get that user name earlier. I'm almost want to up vote him.

Comment: Can you select more than one choice for each answer?

Comment: @JK: That is just the first step. After it has learned enough, it will start answering questions, too.

Comment: @Adam Gent: It says "mutually exclusive choices". So, no.

Comment: Usernames can be shared!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple and intuitive designs are always the best and since they are really simple, we start doubting ourselves ;-). You are doing good except you can also store the correct answer with the Problem itself. Then it is no longer just a Problem. So now it is ProblemAndAnswer or QuizItem.

So this is all OK to store in a single table as multiple columns. **But you also need to understand what it means.** This means that you are making an **assumption** that a question is always going to have 5 choices. If you going to have less than 5 then it is ok as you can store nulls. But what if you are going to have more? This is when the single table model starts falling apart. You would now start thinking that a Question really can have 1 or more choices and would want to split into parent child tables....now you have made a well-informed decision ;-)

Comment: I don't know. Limiting the schema to exactly five answers seems to be bad. Of course, it may exactly match the requirement (today), but if just a little more generality at not too much of complexity cost, I'd make it more flexible there. Keeping it as simple as the requirement (modulo a little headway) allows is a good principle, though.

Answer (score 5):

Properties A through E? No thank you! I'd lay out my tables as follows:

```
Quiz (int QuizId, ...)
Problem (int ProblemId, int QuizId, string Question)
Answer (int AnswerId, int ProblemId, int Index, string Answer)
```

The field names should be self-explanatory (Index is the sort index for the answers of a single question, if their order matters)

Answer (score 3):

The table `Question` has an `id` and a `description`, which is the text of the question ("Are cats secretly dogs?").

Edit: Additionally, the `Question` table has a `correct_answer_id`, which corresponds to the correct row in the `Answer` table.

The table `Answer` has a `question_id`, linking it back to its `Question`, and a `description`, which is the text of the answer ("It depends on the color of your cat.").

With this schema, questions don't have a hardcoded number of answers.

Comment: Plus a field on Question for the correct answer. Or it can be hard-coded to have the first answer be the correct one always, if you are going to shuffle them anyway when displaying them (but then don't use the question_id directly in hidden fields, or the user will start to cheat). Or a field an Answer to mark it correct (which would allow extending the system for questions with multiple correct answers).

Answer (score 1):

I am working on same kind of database structure. It is better to have a choices table to insert choices against a specific question id. Quiz ID is a separate table that includes questionids and duration of test.